# tvOS: Call into JavaScript from Swift for TVML app

Tags: swift, tvos, tvml, tvjs

I know calling into Swift code can be done from JavaScript ([Call Swift code from an Apple TV TVML TVJS JavaScript App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38187957/call-swift-code-from-an-apple-tv-tvml-tvjs-javascript-app)) but I'm wondering if the reverse is true?

Basically I have a long running asynchronous Swift function that will be made when the user interacts with a button on a TVML page and I need to call back into the JavaScript when its completed

Comment: Have you seen this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33081565/how-to-bridge-tvml-javascriptcore-to-uikit-objective-c-swift ? If so please provide some code that is not working for you.

Comment: Thats exactly what I was looking for... my googling had failed me. I'll try that out and either close this question or update it based upon what is going wrong. Thanks @RomanPodymov

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Roman suggested above. This answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/33573770/1135276) did everything I needed. I've been using typescript so I had to play a little with the server side implementation but the patterns the answer used were exactly what I needed.

Comment: I voted to close as a duplicate but until then in case people fail to find the other answer the same way I did.